# ASP.NET MVC cannot pass my hidden model back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

model class

```
public int Year { get; set; } = 0;
public int Odometer { get; set; }
public string ImageURL { get; set; } = "NA";
public string Category { get; set; } = "NA";
```

My View

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label AutoLText">Has Vehicle Documents</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.VehDocuments, new SelectList(Model.GetYesNo()),new { @class = "form-control AutoL" })
                <span asp-validation-for="VehDocuments" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImageURL)
                <input type="submit" value="Add New Vehicle" class="btn MVButton_2" />
            </div>
```

so if i dont have the **"@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImageURL)"** in my view then the "ImageURL" will not be passed to the controller.

using the "**HiddenFor**" is kind of a security issue ? as if they change the string it will mess-up the image path to the controller and save it to the DB.

How can i go around this ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have `ImageURL` in the ViewModel if the user isn't supposed to see or change it.

Comment: hmm, as the ViewModel **ImageURL** is generated on the "create" view (GUID) so it will not be added to the DB at that point, i use it as a UniqueKey as that is used to call a **Upload** function on the same view and the **ImageURL** is a reference for storing location before anything is added to the DP...

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually asking is "How to preserve model's properties' original values when they were not edited". There are multiple options, and yes, *using hidden fields* is one of them. Take a look at [this post on social msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46b5e681-bc1a-4d55-a5e7-762bd82cc19f/posting-a-view-how-to-preserve-models-properties-original-values-when-they-were-not-edited?forum=aspmvc).